# What's wrong with using rectangles rather than triangles in Goursat's proof?

Tags: complex-analysis, math-history

I am reading the article *On Goursat's Proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem* written by Harald Hanche-Olsen. In a historical remark, the author wrote that

> Goursat presented a proof in 1884 for the case of a simple closed curve, by dividing up the interior into small squares...

> Moore cleaned up the proof a bit, paying more careful attention to the treatment of the boundary curve. He also introduced the current idea of proof by contradiction, by subdividing and always selecting a part where the desired conclusion is maximally violated, and then applying the definition of the derivative at the resulting limit point.

> Pringsheim presented a more severe criticism of Goursat's treatment of the boundary curve in 1901. He pointed out that these problems disapper if the proof technique is applied to a simple geometric figure such as a triangle.

Since some modern textbooks (such as Bak and Newman, Cartan, or Beardon) do use rectangles to present Goursat's proof, I don't understand what is the issue with rectangles. What is Pringsheim's criticism all about? Is his criticism justified? Is it OK to use rectangles?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you. It makes sense. I am happy to accept it if you turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misreading this. As I interpret it, what he says is that the proof technique of subdividing into rectangles works fine if the boundary curve is a triangle, but that there is an additional argument needed to get from there to a more general boundary curve: “Then the theorem follows for simple polygonal paths in a simply connected domain by triangulating the interior of the path, and finally one gets it for a general path by approximating it by polygonal paths.”